# Vibration sensor to detect knock on apartment wall

Tags: wireless, sensor

So I want to buy a wireless vibration sensor I can use to detect knock on apartment wall.

My neighbour knocks on wall and I want to document it.

I thought there would be some type of ready to use wifi or bluetooth devices that could stand in for this job.

But I haven't seen anything I can buy. I have seen some DIY projects but I am not sure I want to dive into hardware development.

Are there any devices on market that could stand in for this job or really easy DIY projects to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what part of DIY you find easy. Theres a lot of ways to skin this cat, but the DIY requires hardware components and programming.

You can use audio, and count the knocking peaks, but this would pick up other unwanted audio, and you might need programming.

You can use a devices like Arduino or ESP8266, or even a raspberry pi connected to a physical 'knock sensor' component, but you'd need to write some code to read input when the knock triggers, and write a timestamp to disk, if you need time data.

This would be relatively easy to achieve if you are familiar with coding this hardware.

For cheap, you can get arduino data logger with built in SD card functionality to write the data to disk. You'd find more than enough help and support writing and wiring through the fine folks on the stack networks. Don't know any devices specifically designed for this purpose, but if you want WiFi, you can look at the Esp8266 or Huzzah from adafruit, or ESP32 all support built-in wifi, and you can even serve a webpage from the device and make a web-interface if you want to take it that far. All these solutions involves DIY hardware and programming tho.